Umbraco: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: title error
I upgraded my website to Umbraco 14 and when I try to add new items I the following error message:
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: title

Then I run the following command on the database:
SELECT cct.[alias], [contentTypeId], cpt.[alias], count(cpt.[Alias]) FROM [cmsPropertyType] cpt JOIN [cmsContentType] cct on cpt.contentTypeId = cct.nodeid GROUP BY cct.[alias], [contentTypeId], cpt.[alias] HAVING COUNT(cpt.[alias]) > 1

And this what I got:


What should I do now in order to fix it? Like, how do I fix it?
Please advise.
Thanks.

You must have a Primary Key set in the database.  You cannot add two items with the same key.  The key is "Title".

Under which table? Where can I find these primary key set?

I cannot tell which table.  The [key] will show up in the database definitions of the columns.
